# How to make model class that receive data

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, listview, android-fragments

How i Receive this data into to Model class i want to make a model class like getter setter andi use data from getter setter.

> I want to make Model class
>   Basically i store it into variables not in separate class so i want to make model class

**> Here is my code**

```
 class JSONAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
      /*  dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        dialog.setMessage("Loading, please wait");
        dialog.setTitle("Connecting server");
        dialog.show();
        dialog.setCancelable(false);*/
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "fetch data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {

            //------------------>>

            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
            int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            if (status == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);


                JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(data);

                latLngList.clear();
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject obj = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

                    longitudeServer = obj.getString("longi");
                    latitudeServer = obj.getString("lati");
                    uniqueidSserver = obj.getString("uniqueid");

                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(latitudeServer), Double.parseDouble(longitudeServer));
                    latLngList.add(latLng);

                }


                return true;

            }


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;


    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Receicve data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        if (result == false) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to fetch data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        try {

            if (marker != null) {
                mMap.clear();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Remove", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
            for (LatLng object : latLngList)

                marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("User Name").position(object).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.female4)));

            System.out.println(marker.getPosition() + "  Marker position.......");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // mMap.clear();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although @Guillaume answer is correct, i would like to suggest a better and faster way. You can use a third party library [LoganSquare](https://github.com/bluelinelabs/LoganSquare) to serialize and parse your models to and from JSON respectively. You just have to annotate your models and use LoganSquare class to parse data.

In your case it would be like this: (pay close attention to annotations above class name and fields)

```
@JsonObject
public class MyServer {

  @JsonField(name = "longi")
  public String longitudeServer;

  @JsonField(name = "lati")
  public String latitudeServer;

  @JsonField(name = "uniqueid")
  public String uniqueidSserver;

  public MyServer(){
  // blank constructor is required
  }
}
```

Now use LoganSquare static class to parse the json response received from server:

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
    MyServer s = LoganSquare.parse(jsonarray.getJSONObject(i).toString(), MyServer.class);

    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(s.getLatidude()), Double.parseDouble(s.getLongitude())); // Use your server's methods
    latLngList.add(latLng);

}
```

Comment: Rafy Bhai i received an error here please help me what i do?
for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
   ModelClass s = LoganSquare.parse(jsonarray.getJSONObject(i).toString(), ModelClass.class);

                        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(s.getLatitude()), Double.parseDouble(s.getLongitude())); // Use your server's methods
                        latLngList.add(latLng);

                    }

Comment: My Model Class is

@JsonObject

public class ModelClass {

    @JsonField(name = "longi")
    public String longitudeServer;

    @JsonField(name = "lati")
    public String latitudeServer;

    @JsonField(name = "uniqueid")
    public String uniqueidSserver;

    public String getLongitude(){
        return longitudeServer;
    }

    public String getLatitude(){
        return latitudeServer;
    }

    public String getUniqueId(){
        return uniqueidSserver;
    }

    public ModelClass(){
        // blank constructor is required
    }
    //... More setter and getter here
}

Comment: An error occured while executing doInBackground()

                        ModelClass s = LoganSquare.parse(jsonarray.getJSONObject(i).toString(), ModelClass.class);

Comment: how is that possible with @SerializedName?
Please anyone help me

Answer (score 1):

First define your desired model into a class with for example a constructor allwing to create a new instance from a JSONObject

```
class JSONAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
    class MyServer {

        private String longitudeServer;
        private String latitudeServer;
        private String uniqueidSserver;

        public MyServer(JSONObject obj){
            try{
                longitudeServer = obj.getString("longi");
                latitudeServer = obj.getString("lati");
                uniqueidSserver = obj.getString("uniqueid");
            }catch(JSONException jse){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public String getLongitude(){
            return longitudeServer;
        }

        public void setLongitude(String longitudeServer){
            this.longitudeServer = longitudeServer;
        }

        //... More setter and getter here
    }
    // ... The existing code of your async task here
}
```

Once this done your can instanciate a new MyServer and use its getter/setter

```
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject obj = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
        MyServer s = new MyServer(obj); // Create your server from the JSONObject 
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(s.getLatidude()), Double.parseDouble(s.getLongitude())); // Use your server's methods
        latLngList.add(latLng);

    }
```

Comment: Guillaume These lines show me the error
public MyServer(JSONObject obj){
        longitudeServer = obj.getString("longi");
        latitudeServer = obj.getString("lati");
        uniqueidSserver = obj.getString("uniqueid");
    }

Comment: Thanksssssssssssssss Guillaume i resolve the issue again thanks

Comment: @Ahmad public MyServer(JSONObject obj) is no a method, it is the constructor the class MyServer. You must create a new class "MyServer". You can do it in a new file MyServer.java or as an inner class whitin your existing code... The error message you gave look like you are trying to create a method...

Comment: My answer is updated to show you how to make it using an inner class.

Comment: Thanks alot Guillaume